Unable to access a variable in a NetCDF file in Julia
I have a NetCDF file from which I want to access the contents of a variable "wavelengths." The structure of the file is somewhat like this:
Groups
  Dataset: /Users/arpitasen/Desktop/Sanghavi/Data/EMIT_L2A_RFL_001_20220903T163129_2224611_012.nc
  Group: sensor_band_parameters

  Variables
    wavelengths     (285)
      Datatype:    Union{Missing, Float32} (Float32)
      Dimensions:  bands
      Attributes:
       _FillValue           = -9999.0
       long_name            = Wavelength Centers
       units                = nm

I am trying to access the variable using the following code:
using NCDatasets
nc_file_path = "file.nc"
ncfile = NCDataset(nc_file_path, "r")
wv = ncfile["wavelengths"]

I am getting the following error, which is weird. What exactly is going on here?:
ERROR: LoadError: NetCDF error: Variable 'wavelengths' not found in file


I cannot see the file you are using, but you could try executing "  dump(ncfile) "
to see if the wavelengths are in the set you loaded.

Variable "wavelengths" is inside the group "sensor_band_parameters":
using NCDatasets
nc_file_path = "file.nc"
nc_file = NCDataset(nc_file_path, "r")
sbp_group = nc_file.group["sensor_band_parameters"]
wv = sbp_group["wavelengths"]

Result:
wavelengths (285)
  Datatype:    Union{Missing, Float32} (Float32)
  Dimensions:  bands
  Attributes:
   _FillValue           = -9999.0
   long_name            = Wavelength Centers
   units                = nm

https://alexander-barth.github.io/NCDatasets.jl/stable/dataset/#Groups
